# Define abstract method in another (from abstract parent) parent?

Tags: c++, inheritance, abstract

I hoped that in my code the C++ would notice that in class D the abstract method from class C is already defined in A. But that is not the case. The similar code would works in Java (where C acts like interface). Currently it fails with output:

```
error: cannot declare variable ‘x’ to be of abstract type ‘D’
note:   because the following virtual functions are pure within ‘D’:
note:   virtual void C::secret()
```

What would be the best way to make it work?

```
#include <iostream>

class A {
  public:
    virtual void secret() {
      std::cout<<"secret a func\n";
    };
};

class B: public A {};

class C {
  public:
    virtual void secret() = 0;
};

class D: public B, public C {};

int main() {
  D x;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: look up *the diamond problem* and virtual inheritance

Comment: @BeyelerStudios Irrelevant to the question? `C` doesn't inherit from `A`.

Comment: @Barry relevant because that's what he's trying to do (only missing part is the common interface of `A` and `C`) - also every explanation of the diamond problem describes the difference between `A::secret` and `C::secret` in detail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your hierarchy looks like:

[image]

`A` has a virtual member function named `secret`. And `C` has an *entirely unrelated* pure virtual member function named `secret`. Since `D` doesn't provide an override `C::secret`, `D` is also considered an abstract class. It does not matter that `A::secret` exists - `A` does not inherit from `C` and only base classes may provide virtual overrides.

If you want to use `A::secret` to override `C::secret`, you would have to do so explicitly:

```
class D: public B, public C {
    void secret() override {
        A::secret();
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

The class `D` is apparently abstract as it does not provide an implementation of `secret` as defined in `C`. The type `D` reads ambiguous as it is not clear whether its member `secret` would be inherited from `C` or `A`.